# What is the path for the executable needed for the <com:ExeServer />

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, appxmanifest

Basically I have a WPF app that I wanted to use Windows Notifications in. I did everything the microsoft guide said, but I am not sure what path should I use for the Executable property in com:ExeServer.

I tried my apps name, my package name.

```xml
        <com:Extension Category="windows.comServer">
          <com:ComServer>
            <com:ExeServer Executable="<any path>" Arguments="-ToastActivated" DisplayName="Toast activator">
              <com:Class Id="<my GUID>" DisplayName="Toast activator"/>
            </com:ExeServer>
          </com:ComServer>
        </com:Extension>
```

I always get the:
"Cannot register the X-X-X- _1.0.0.0_neutral__jdwztr3qrgq8m package. The path "the path i put" was not found." Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. I solved it. In case anyone else has the same problem, make sure you've double checked all your GUIDs are the same, and also that you typed the folder/directory name correctly.

My bad.

Comment: If you have resolved your issue please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it as accepted to convenient people who visit this thread later.